# Rspec tests: it { should respond_to() }

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec2

If you have a list of attributes that you are testing for their presence and you have the following:

```
before do
  @attr = Employee.new(name: "One",
                       email: "onetwo@three.com")
end

subject { @attr }

it { should respond_to(:name) }
it { should respond_to(:email) }

it { should be_valid }
```

Can you then test for the reverse, namely if these attributes are blank using:

```
it { should_not respond_to(:reverse, :blank) }
it { should_not be_valid }
```

I did try the above, but I do not understand the issues all that well, even after reading [this discussion](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/26).

Does anyone know how to use the same initialization to test for presence and then to turn around and test for blank attributes?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to even test here? Testing if something responds to a method and testing whether the return value of that method is blank or not are disjoint concepts.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what `respond_to` does in your tests. When you do

```
it { should respond_to(:name) }
```

You're asserting that `@attr.respond_to(:name)` returns `true`, meaning that the method is present, not that it's returning a value. If you want to test that there's a value being returned, you could do something like:

```
its(:name){ should be_present }
```

That will make sure that the result of calling the `name` method returns a non-false, non-empty value. Then, when you reverse that test

```
its(:name){ should_not be_present }
```

You're asserting that the `name` method is returning blank. You'll have to create a different setup for the second test, since you're testing an object in a different state.

Comment: Thanks @Emily ... I sure did have the wrong understanding of respond_to. I need to do more reading and experimentation to get the fullness of your guidance. Does the validate for :presence meet the bar when it comes to whether or not there is a value?

Comment: The great thing about Rspec is how easy it is to test that sort of stuff yourself. When you call `be_present` in Rspec, it's calling `present?` on the model. Same with `respond_to` calling `respond_to?`. You can then easily test those methods in IRB. To answer directly, though, `present?` returns `true` for anything except `""`, `" "`, `nil`, `false`, `[]` and `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your individual tests on the user object should be more like this:

```
it "should have an email attribute" do
  @attr.should respond_to(:email) }
end
```

However, if you're testing a class, might I suggest something more along the lines of this for your test:

```
before (:each) do
  @attr = {name: "One", email: "onetwo@three.com"}
end
```

Then your first test ensures creation works like so:

```
it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
  Employee.create!(@attr)
end
```

Once you've established that's working you, can continue on with your other tests and have the employee automatically get created like so:

```
describe "Attributes and method tests" do
  before (:each) do
    @employee = Employee.create(@attr)
  end

  it "should have a name attribute" do
    @employee.should respond_to(:name)
  end

  it "should have an email attribute" do
    @employee.should respond_to(:email) }
  end

  # etc... (to test other attributes or methods)
end
```

To answer your question about reversing the test and specifying that it's not valid if the attributes are blank, I would try something like this.  These tests would be good if you had validations for presence:

```
it "should not be valid with a blank email" do
  Employee.new(@attr.merge(:email => '').should_not be_valid
end

it "should not be valid with a blank name" do
  Employee.new(@attr.merge(:name => '').should_not be_valid
end
```

Comment: This is subjective and doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question at first.  Thought you were saying that you were having difficulty understanding proper format for writing tests.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Well it's not *my* question, but leaving the original things you had in is still just misleading subjective fluff, IMO.

Comment: I suppose.  It just seemed based on the way he worded his question that he was an inexperienced user of rspec so I was trying to be helpful and give some pointers.

Comment: Yes I do have validate for presence in my model ... that was helpful that you pointed it out. Thanks.